# Create a Shiny interactive plot in a Quarto book

Tags: python, r, shiny, quarto

Is there a way to create a Shiny interactive plot in a Quarto **book**? I've seen a way to do this in [Quarto websites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73154111/quarto-create-a-shiny-interactive-qmd-document-within-a-quarto-website) and [Quarto slides](https://quarto.org/docs/presentations/revealjs/demo/index.html#/interactive-slides-1), but I haven't found a solution to Quarto books. Help?

#### 2022/Oct/10 update:

- For Python users, the [Shinylive Extension](https://quarto.org/docs/blog/posts/2022-10-25-shinylive-extension/) now makes it possible to embed Shinylive applications in Quarto documents and run the application inside the web browser without the need for a server

Shinylive Extension

Comment: You can't directly do this from the `quarto`, because `quarto book` is static, but shiny is not. As an alternative, you can try to embed that app. See this detailed answer on this https://stackoverflow.com/a/73391579/10858321

Comment: Thanks! This is very clarifying. This might be a long shot, but pershaps someone will create a way to convert Shiny apps to ObservableJS code